# Showdown automatic header anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, showdown

[Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) is markdown to HTML converter written in Javascript.

Is there a way to configure showdown (or write an extension) that automatically adds `<a>` link to current header anchor?

For example:

```
(new showdown.Converter()).makeHtml(' # Some header ')
<h1 id="someheader">Some header <a href="#someheader">link</a> </h1>
```